# Create subdomain - WAMP

Tags: windows, server, wamp, subdomain

I have "Windows Server 2012 R2" with a website already setup on it.

The domain is hosted at GoDaddy.
In GoDaddy I created a subdomain A record entry in the Zone File and pointed that to the same IP as my current site that is running on my WAMP server.

However how do I get my Windows Server/WAMP to use the subdomain?

Right now the subdomain I want to use is "dev" so if I go to "dev.mywebsite.com"
it takes me to the same place as my actual domain. Not sure how to setup the subdomain part on the WAMP side of things.

Comment: created a virtual host in apache ?

Comment: I followed this guide: [link](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/create-virtual-hosts-in-a-wamp-server/) and have

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www"
    ServerName mydomain.local
    ErrorLog "logs/mydomain.log"
    CustomLog "logs/mydomain-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>`

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\subdomains\dev"
    ServerName dev.mydomain.local
    ErrorLog "logs/mydomain.log"
    CustomLog "logs/mydomain-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>`

Subdomain still forwards

Comment: Got it working by trying various ways to setup virtual host. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in 4 steps:

```
Step 1: Create the folder which will hold your sub-domains
Step 2: Make sure httpd-vhosts.conf file is included
Step 3: Configuring Apache VirtualHosts
Step 4: Updating Windows Host File
```

Those steps are explained in detail in [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180323082634/http://www.axertion.com/tutorials/2012/03/how-to-setup-local-subdomains-using-wampserver/)